# Scraping certain parts of a website [Python]

Tags: python, csv

Let's say we have a website *www.example.com* 
and I need 5 certain elements from the website, I have found every element and declared them using BeautifulSoup.

```
g_data1 = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "title"})

for item in g_data1:
try
print item.****[3].text
except:
pass
```

Now I have to save this information in a CSV file named ****.csv
This is my code for trying to save it in the CSV file:

```
def save_csv(f, tvseries):
'''
Output a CSV file containing highest ranking TV-series.
'''
import urllib2

url = *example url*
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

with open('****.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.read())
```

Im getting the entire html website.. because i've obviously declared it to grab the url but can someone explain me a different kind of approach, because I don't really understand how to :L

with kind regards,

1337

Comment: *UPDATE*
I have tried the easiest way to do this:
     c = csv.writer(open("tvseries.csv", "wb"))
     c.writerow(['Title', 'Ranking', 'Genre', 'Actors', 'Runtime'])

Comment: You haven't really asked a question.  The first part of your code is (at least) not properly formatted indentation-wise.  What do you mean with the ****?  If you have the list of items you need to pass that list to save_csv(...) and write to your output file

Comment: Im sorry I accidently pressed enter :P I was editing it:
*UPDATE*
I have tried the easiest way to do this:
     c = csv.writer(open("***.csv", "wb"))
     c.writerow(['Title', '***', '***', '***', '****'])

Now i've got the first row, but that's because i've manually put it in the writerow. 
I need to input the data i've received from g_data1 into the csv file, but I don't understand how. I still get the entire website printed out... and everything is on the first line :/

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Python's csv module.
Specifically the [CSVWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects).
Take the text items you grabbed using BeautifulSoup and write them into the CSV file.